# Nodejs Api data not saving to array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am getting data from udemy api using a function. 
i cannot save the output of that function to an array

Here is the full code. 
I wanted to assign the api data to the courses array defined in react.

```
.then(response => {
      this.setState({ courses: response.data }, () => {});
    });
```

I think i cannot use .then in an imported udemy-api function written in nodejs ?
It says response not defined in error. Kindly help. Just started learning reactjs.

I used this udemy-api nodejs from github https://github.com/monatis/udemy-api

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
    import "./App.css";

    class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          courses: []
        };
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        this.getCourses();
      }

      getCourses() {
        const Udemy = require("udemy-api");
        let udemyApiClient = new Udemy(
          "client",
          "secret"
        );
        udemyApiClient.get("courses?language=en&price=price-free", function(
          err,
          res,
          body
        ) {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
          .then(response => {
      this.setState({ courses: response.data }, () => {});
    }); // this is not working i want to assign the api data i get to courses array
        });
      }
      render() {
        const coursesItems = this.state.courses.map((courses, i) => {
          return <li>{courses.title}</li>;
        });
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Courses</h1>
            <ul>{coursesItems}</ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: Ideally, you should use componendDidMount instead componentWillMount, when doing any side-effect work... like calling some async function

Comment: I can get the output "body" from the api and display it on console using the console.log(body). But when i assign that to the array courses. Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

The response from the API should be contained in the "body" you're getting back.

```
udemyApiClient.get("courses?language=en&price=price-free", function(err, res, body) { 
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(body) 
});
```

Comment: Yes i get the body response and i can see that in the inspect element console. But i cannot assign that output to the courses array. That's my issue. I tried using .then .

Comment: If i use console.log after the   if (err) return console.error(err); i get the body data from the api in the console.

Comment: Then you should be able to set the state of courses with the body data you're receiving this.setState({ courses: body.data })